# Java casting an object passed to method to its original type

Tags: java, reflection

I have a list called itemsData of object of class EtcStruct, but the class can differ depending on the file i want to use (the class is full of variables setters and getters):

```
ObservableList<EtcStruct> itemsData =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Im passing it to the method thats supposed to work for any object type i choose and run invoked method from the file.

```
public static void parseToFile(ObservableList itemsData){
    EtcStruct itemObject = (EtcStruct) itemsData.get(0);
    System.out.print((int)reflectedmethod.invoke(itemObject);
}
```

Code above works , but what i want to achieve is make the method work without editing it's object type to make it more flexible for whatever structclass i plan to use.

I tried something with passing Struct Class name and  .getClass() it returns the original type but i dont know what to do with it to make the new object of itemsData original type and cast the itemsData object.

```
public static void parseToFile(ObservableList itemsData,Class c){
    Object itemObject = c.newInstance();
    Object newobject = curClass.newInstance();
    newobject = c.cast(itemsList.get(0));
}
```

Above seemed dumb to me and obviously didnt work.

Comment: Why are you trying to cast it? And why are you using raw types?

Comment: You should not have to downcast the argument. Doing so defeats the purpose of inheritance and overrides. If the argument is `Observable`, then the method promises only to use `Observable` behaviors. If you need `EtcStruct` behavior then declare that as the argument type. Also, don't use reflection to hack around architecture mistakes. This isn't a use case for reflection, it's a use case for type- or object-oriented programming.

Comment: How would you go about parsing binary files of different structure in java? The thing I'm trying to do is to just quickly generate setters and getters for the corresponding fields and reflect them in the parser method.
The only thing missing here is what I posted, about letting the method know which struct Class is called.

Comment: Actually,i agree with ***@shmosel***,The more flexible function is,The more concealed holes.When something is wrong,It's difficult for us to find 'them'.So,just keep it simply!

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment I understand better why one would use reflection in your case. A GUI builder/editor is an example where reflection is used to provide an interface to set/get the values of components. Still, IMHO, reflection isn't a tool you would design for when you own the classes and are the primary designer. If possible you should strive for something more like this:

```
interface Parsable {
    default int parse() {
        System.out.println("Here I do something basic");
        return 0;
    }
}

class BasicStruct implements Parsable { }

class EtcStruct implements Parsable {

    @Override
    public int parse() {
        System.out.println("Here I do something specific to an EtcStruct");
        return 1;
    }
}

// If some structs have a parent-child relationship
// you can alternatively `extend EtcStruct` for example.
class OtherStruct extends EtcStruct {

    @Override
    public int parse() {
        super.parse();
        System.out.println("Here I do something specific to an OtherStruct");
        return 2;
    }
}

void parseToFile(Parsable parsable) {
    System.out.println(parsable.parse());
}

// If you use a generic with a specific class you don't
// have to guess or care which kind it is!
void parseToFile(ObservableList<Parsable> parsables) {
    for (Parsable p : parsables) {
        parseToFile(p);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObservableList<Parsable> parsables = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    parsables.add(new BasicStruct());
    parsables.add(new EtcStruct());
    parsables.add(new OtherStruct());
    parseToFile(parsables);
}
```

*Output:*

```
Here I do something basic
0
Here I do something specific to an EtcStruct
1
Here I do something specific to an EtcStruct
Here I do something specific to an OtherStruct
2
```

Of course, this is just an example that needs to be altered to meet your needs.

But what I still don't get is if you're able to parse *from* a file why you can't parse to one. Nonetheless, I slapped [some code](https://github.com/ChiefTwoPencils/bean-help/blob/master/src/main/java/com/robertwilk/beanhelp/StructParser.java) together to show you how I might parse an object to a file, manually, when dealing with `Object`s only.

The idea is to satisfy a bean-like contract. That is, each structure should provide a parameter-less constructor, all fields you want managed by reflection will follow Java naming convention and will have both a public setter and getter.

Don't get caught up in the file writing; that will be determined by your needs. Just notice that by following this convention I can treat any `Object` as a parsable structure.  A less refined version here for reference:

```
public void parseToFile(Object object) throws IOException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("example" + object.getClass().getSimpleName());
    List<Method> getters = Arrays.stream(object.getClass().getMethods())
            .filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("get") && !method.getName().endsWith("Class"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (Method getter : getters) {
        String methodName = getter.getName();
        String key = String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(methodName.charAt(3))) +
                methodName.substring(4, methodName.length());
        fos.write((key + " : " + String.valueOf(getter.invoke(object)) + "\n").getBytes());
    }
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: Im writing an editor for files of specific binary structures,(about 20 of them). List keeps the objects (again with fields based on the structure) of the corresponding struct Class:
e.g. class Struct1{int smth, float smth, String smth3 etc} 
the structures have their setters and getters, for parsing from the file im reflecting the setter methods and invoking them to the object then adding the object to the list, that works well, the parsing to file on the other hand is what bothers me.. Im new to java and programming in general so Im not even sure if its at least a decent approach.

Comment: because of the number of different structures i wanted to make the parsing methods reusable for any of them,no matter the number of fields or types, so i dont have to set it up when the fields are as many as 30++

Comment: @kthxbai2, please re-read my answer; it's been entirely edited based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just still use Generics to keep static objects typing. Try to parametrize your function parseToFile. Here is an example:

```
public static void parseToFile(ObservableList<EtcStruct> itemsData){
  EtcStruct itemObject = itemsData.get(0);
  System.out.print((int)reflectedmethod.invoke(itemObject);
}
```

Comment: i had it like that at first, but im trying to make the method reusable for other data structures stored in like in example EtcStruct.

Comment: In object-oriented programming for adding flaxibility usually using interfaces and polimorfism. You can craete interface called 'EtcStruct', with method named getInt(). Method parseToFile will takes an parametrized ObservableList by EtcStruct and its derived classes. For example your mathod can be implemented like that:
public static void test(ObservableList<? extends EtcStruct> items) {
  EtcStruct item =  items.get(0);
  System.out.println(item.getInt());
}